# Sequelize Error: Unhandled rejection TypeError: val.replace is not a function?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using `PostgreSQL` and `Sequelize` in my `nodejs` app and getting the error:

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: val.replace is not a function ?

I have explored many answers but none of them helped me.

I have a table, name `permissions` and this table has following columns and records:

```
id           userId                      groupIds

1          xyz@test.com               { 253,254,255 }
2          abc@test.com               { 253,254,255 }
3          xyzabc@test.com            { 253,255 }
```

`groupIds` is the array of `integer`.

I want to access those records which has given `groupId` in `groupIds` as:

```
const Models = require('./../../../models/'); // declared all models here correctly.


var getUser = function (groupId) {
  let condition={ where: { $in:{groupIds:groupId} },attributes: ['id', 'userId ] };
        Models.permissions.findAll(condition)
            .then((users) => {
                 console.log(users);
            });
}

getUser(254);
```

Also, I want to add that if I write below condition then it's working fine:

```
let condition = { where: { id: 3 }, attributes: ['id', 'userId'] };
```

Where I am doing wrong?

According to package.json the versions are

```
 "sequelize": "^3.27.0", "sequelize-cli": "^2.5.1"
```

I don't want to update sequelize so can not use `[Sequelize.Op.in]`

Answer (score 0):

How is the field `permissions.groupIds` defined?  Looks like an array... and if so, I don't think IN will work.  You might try ANY, i.e.

```
let condition={ where: { sequelize.fn('ANY(groupIds)') : groupId },attributes: ['id', 'userId ] };
```

or maybe

```
let condition={ where: {sequelize.col('groupId[s]'), groupId)},attributes: ['id', 'userId ] };
```

This syntax may not be correct - am using MySql which doesn't have arrays like Postgres ....

Comment: Thanks@ KenOn10,  the syntax { sequelize.fn('ANY(groupIds)') : groupId } is not correct, Getting error (property) sequelize: any
',' expected.ts(1005)

Comment: Does this work any better?  `{where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('ANY', sequelize.col('groupIds')), groupId) ,attributes: ['id', 'userId ]}`

Comment: I have checked with the above condition but getting error "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: syntax error at or near "ANY"".